# Display mobile native number selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am trying to find out if it is possible to display mobile native range picker or at least single number selection.

What I am trying to achieve is to have input field in which when you tap it opens up this special input that is on mobiles now, where you basically have numbers from x-y and you can scroll up and down through them and select your desired number.

I tried using input type "number" but that only brings up keyboard in numeric state.

The only way I can think of is having those inputs as select boxes, but I need to use this for price range selection which is usually from 100 to 35,000. And I wouldn't want to have 35,000 option tags...

I have found this: http://demo.mobiscroll.com/ but its insanely expensive, and I would still like to bring up the native widget.

Thank you for ideas.

Comment: Expecting users to scroll through 35,000 values to get to the one they want is not particularly user friendly, regardless of how it's implemented.

Comment: @RobG yes, you can see it live on pc here: http://zanadu.cn/search/searchHotel?SphinxSearchForm[all_hotels]=1 its same on mobile, but boss decided he wants something more "native" on mobile... With the widget im trying to find the scrolling speeds up exponentially so it would not be that hard to scroll, or we could add steps.. If I cannot find how to call that widget, I will either create selectboxes of ranges which will restrict usage o just have two "number" inputs, which won't be too funky.. Its basically just trying to please boss and keep some sanity..

Comment: Wow, a 15MB home page. Not sure mobile users are going to find that particularly useful even if they wait forever for it to load. You seriously need a way to sort/group/filter search results, don't just list about 350 results and expect users to sift through them manually.

Comment: @RobG yeah, again... our management... I have the script ready for lazyloading, its working and all, but this is the decision for now... Unfortunately its one of the jobs where I became the code monkey :) but not for much longer yay:)